# Developing a product for commercial use compatible with Google Home/Alexa

Tags: smart-home, alexa, google-home

I would like to know whether there are any restrictions/rules when developing a product which is compatible with Google/Alexa or maybe even other hubs. Do I need to get some license or follow some rules?

Comment: What do Google Home and Amazon Alexa support pages say about it?

Comment: As @Bence said, you need to go read the terms of service which are available from the respective vendors website's

Comment: I have tried looking but couldnt really find an accurate answer to my question. I have even contacted google home support and they could not answer my question for some reason. They forwarded me to google developers section. Im looking how to contact them

Comment: Also, support page suggested asking in stack overflow with actions-on-google tag. But I am not  able to add this tag for some reason. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Documentation includes a check list which has the ToS

https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/launching

Especially read the first item on the list on that page.

For Amazon you should probably start here:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/devices/connected-devices/business-resources

And look at "Certification and Badging" section

Comment: My only concern : "Note: In order to have your Smart Home Action certified and released to production, your Action must support commercially available products.". How can I have my product commercially available if I havent yet got the google home certification? I want to get it certified and fully compatible with google home before I release it commercially

Comment: That's between you and Google, not something we can answer

Comment: @zazas321 it says "released to production" there are unreleased states of Alexa skills which you put of for certification with your product which is at that time also unreleased. Then you get the certification,you can print fancy Alexa logos on your products and align with Amazon on when you start selling and the skill goes live. The specific timings are up for discussion between you and Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

As of know they don’t have any restrictions as they give you permission to tether with your television music player and etc , they don’t have any problem by accessing your own product through Alexa or google assistant., if you can make effective product you can do that and on other hand you are just going to pass the voice command to Alexa and Alexa should react to your own device that is the thing you have to take care so the choosing methodology and devices does the matter here , do more research on this and then start to develop your product